# Windows 8.1 lock screen changes on remote desktop connect

Tags: windows-8.1, remote-desktop

The lock screen of my home computer is customised, which shows up (as expected) on boot-up. However, whenever I remote desktop to the computer, its lock screen becomes one of the default Windows lock scrren images.

How is the behaviour being governed, and how to change it?

Answer (score 0):

Since the answerer has abandoned his own answer...

The way to control the global lock screen is via Group Policy. In this case, Local Group Policy

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2787100/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0

There is a policy “**Force a specific default lock screen image**” under the policy path

Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Personalization

when running the *gpedit.msc* management console.

Comment: hmmmm, after a month, this seems to have stopped working; reverted back to default Windows lock screen.

Answer (score -1):

The default Windows screen images is to have better performance while remotely accessing a machine. But the settings can be change with the following steps.

Windows Start button > search for "Remote Desktop Connection" > maximize the 'Options' > go to 'Performance' tab > check the "Desktop Background" box. If required, do a restart to take effect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I stated "lock screen" and nothing about desktop wallpaper.

Comment: Ok. Please check out this article. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2787100/en-us

Comment: You should revise the answer to the group policy one, or make a new answer, as that turns out to be the way to go.